# Incorrect Right-Click Menu from Task Bar

Tags: autohotkey

I need to Right-Click a task bar icon in order to launch a program, but when AHK Right-Clicks, it brings up the wrong menu

This is what it looks like when I do it:

[image]

Here's my script:

```
#+e::
    CoordMode, Mouse, Screen
    Click, right, 2224, 2118
Return
```

This is the result of the script:

[image]

How do I get the correct Right-Click Menu?

---

Things I've tried:

- MouseClick
- Click

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result of the script is the "SHIFT + right click menu".

Try adding KeyWait to your code:

```
<#+e::  ; "<#" means LWin
    KeyWait, LWin
    KeyWait, Shift
    CoordMode, Mouse, Screen
    Click, right, 2224, 2118
Return
```